# Assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'int (^__strong)(void)'

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to call a block that returns me a random `finalItemID` (int) according to state of the app. But the app fails to build because of the error:

> Assigning to 'int' from incompatible type 'int (^__strong)(void)'

My code:

```
//block declaration
int(^getMeAnItem)(void)=^int(void)
{
int finalItemID=0;
//some randomization code
return finalItemID;
};

int itemIDToBeChecked=0;
itemIDToBeChecked= getMeAnItem; //red error appears on this line
```

I am not seeing anything wrong going here. I hope you guys can help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To call a block you need to actually call it:

```
itemIDToBeChecked = getMeAnItem();
```

Comment: that was a Big oopsie daisy moment. I should probably cry in a corner for that mistake. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You initialise a variable named getMeAnItem. An initialisation *always* ends in a semicolon. Yours doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

What about parentheses?

```
itemIDToBeChecked = getMeAnItem();
```